# wixcode: How to manage Members' dataset from desktop terminal?

Tags: velo

I have Members Pages on my WixSite. One of these pages is connected to a dataset that each member can modify in order to see their data later on via a specific design.

What I would like to do:
As the webmaster, I want to be able to access and edit each Member's dataset via my own computer (without having to go to the website, connect and manually modify anything).
For example, I would have a code on my desktop, run it through my desktop terminal which would allow me to connect to Wix and modify the Members' dataset.

In other words:
I would like to use WIX API from my terminal or any piece of code on my computer without having to open any browser. It would be like: 1) importing some wix library; 2) Sending my credentials to Wix; 3) sending a request; 4) Getting an answer back from WIX.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what you're specifically trying to accomplish. However, if you want to modify collection data without going to the site that contains the collection, you can write an HTTP function that performs the action you want. Then you can call that HTTP function from any platform.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the input. I would like to use WIX API from my terminal or any piece of code on my computer without having to open any browser. It would be like: 1) importing some wix library; 2) Sending my credentials to Wix; 3) sending a request; 4) Getting an answer back from WIX.

Comment: You would have to build that functionality into your site using HTTP functions.